# awk: output files contain ^M character in filename

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a very long file which looks like this:

```
0a
190  0.121212
191  0.232323
...
0b
190  0.1212
191  0.4545
...
16c
190  0.34654
191  0.567565
...
```

I use awk to split the file into many smaller files using this command:

```
awk '/[0-9][a-c]/{close(x); x=$0;}{print > x;}' spectrum.tsv
```

This works, but the names of the output files all seem to contain a newline character at the end of the filename:
[image]

I have tried to remove the newline character with "sub" like so:

```
awk '/[0-9][a-c]/{close(x); x=$0;}{sub(/^M/,"",x)}{print > x;}' spectrum.tsv
```

But that leads to the same result.

So my question is, how can I avoid the newline character in the output filenames?
I am working on OSX 10.10 btw. The input file is from a Windows machine.

Comment: How did you arrive at `^M` character inside `sub()`? Try to enter `ctrl-v + ctrl-M` instead of `^M` if not tried already.

Comment: was there a DOS/windows - Linux Carriage return problem in your input file?

Comment: @Kent: Yes, the input file is from a windows machine. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `dos2unix` on your files before you let awk process them!
It will remove DOS style line endings, which is probably what is causing your head ache.

Comment: It seems that dos2unix is not available on OSX, but I found this workaround which does the trick: cat foo | col -b > foo2. I found it on http://schmeits.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/dos2unix-alternative-those-darn-m-characters/

Answer (score 2):

You can just set an appropriate record separator in awk to take care of `\r` in input files:

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' '/[0-9][a-c]/{close(x); x=$0;}{print > x;}' spectrum.tsv
```

Here `RS='\r?\n'` sets `RS` as optional `\r` (`^M`) followed by `\n`

Comment: You should mention the multi-char RS makes this gawk-only. Also on some platforms you'll need to add `-v BINMODE=3`.

Comment: I just tried this. It works for the first file, which is written out as "0a". But, the following files are now called "?0b", "?0c", ...

Answer (score 0):

Open in vi editor and go to command mode and then:
type `":%s/[CTRL+V][CTRL+M]//g"`